# Android anti-malware presence detection

Tags: android, security, antimalware

I need to determine if the Android phone where my app is running, has any kind of anti-malware installed. I'd like to avoid hardcoding a kind of list of apps that are known to be anti-malware/anti-virus apps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: _Hey there! You need to add some more description and what have you tried so far in your question else no one would able to help you_

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to ensure that my application only runs on "sufficiently protected" phones. I haven't tried anything out yet.